# “The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable” with int and boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, int

I have to write the condition for this:

```
last_page = ((nl.getLength() == 0) -= 1);
```

In this line am getting following error:

**The left-hand side of an assignment must be a 
 variable**

This is my code:

```
    int current_page = 25;
boolean last_page;
int prev_page;
int next_page;
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
prev_page = (current_page -= 1);
next_page = (current_page += 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

the part `((nl.getLength() == 0)` evaluates to a **boolean value**, and you cannot substract `1` from that.

Comment: then how can i find the last_page value

Comment: don't you want it to be nl.getLength()-1 as some others suggested?

Comment: oh, I see -- last_page is a flag! then just do `last_page = current_page == (nl.getLength()-1);`

Comment: i have developed one android listview example using xml parsing.here i have to hide the button on lastpage.i have used this condition means hide the button on empty page .if(nl.getLength() == 0)...but wish to hide the button on last_page.so how can i hide the button on last_page.please give me solution for this

Comment: hm - seems like you've changed your complete question to something different here. It would be better to create a new question instead of changing the current one (as all the already given answers do not match your new question)

Answer (score 2):

The double `==` sign is a comparative operator. Basically, you're checking that `nl.getLength()` is `0`. This will give you a boolean value (`True` or `False`).

The `-=` sign means "decrement". So `someVar -= 1` will try to subtract `1` from the value of `someVar`.

You can't subtract a number from a boolean because they are different types. This is the reason you are getting your error.

Because you declare `last_page` as a boolean and you mention an if statement, I am assuming you want to check to see if you are on the last page. The code to do that would be this:

```
last_page = (current_page == (nl.getLength() - 1)); //is the current page the last page?
```

Remember that in Java indexes start at `0` and go until `length - 1`. This statement will check to see if the current page is the final index of `nl`

Comment: but `last_page` was declared as `boolean`

Comment: i have developed one android listview example using xml parsing.here i have to hide the button on lastpage.i have used this condition means hide the button on empty page .if(nl.getLength() == 0)...but wish to hide the button on last_page.so how can i hide the button on last_page.please give me solution for this

Comment: @user1780331 I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to check for the last page, the code that I (and several others) have written will work. If you already know how to hide the button `if (nl.getLength() == 0)`, then it is exactly the same for `if (last_page)`. If you do not know how to hide this button then I suggest you make a new question asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

simply use this instead :

```
last_page = nl.getLength() -1;
```

The error you are getting is because of this `(nl.getLength() == 0)` as it will return a boolean `true` or `false` and hence you cannot **subtract( and any other arithmetic operation like add,multiply, etc.) any number from a boolean** it doesn't make sense like this:  `(true - 1)` or `(false +1)`

Comment: int last_page;  also change above line means am getting following error for this if loop:if (last_page)
   {
          btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          pDialog.dismiss();
       }        Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

Comment: rather you should write `if(last_page > any_number)` in your loop

Comment: i have developed one android listview example using xml parsing.here i have to hide the button on lastpage.i have used this condition means hide the button on empty page .if(nl.getLength() == 0)...but wish to hide the button on last_page.so how can i hide the button on last_page.please give me solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Look, `(nl.getLength() == 0)` is not a variable, it's an expression, just like `1 + 1`. The operator `-=` however is not an expression, it wants to decrement a *variable*, that is, take the variable's value, modify it and write it back. How could you "write back" into an expression?

The appropriate CS term would be *lvalue*: a value which you can not only read from, but also write to. Expressions like `(nl.getLength() == 0)` are not lvalues, however the operators like `-=` expect an lvalue to be able to modify it. That's what the error message is basically saying.

On the contrary, in your second example `current_page` is an lvalue.